# .NET Core PrefixOrigin logic

Tags: networking, .net-core, dhcp, subnet

I am porting some Windows code to Linux. Part of the windows objects properties was not implemented in .net core's linux implementation. UnicastIPAddressInformation.PrefixOrigin is one of them.

.NET Core code docs show define it as:

> value that identifies the source of a unicast IP address prefix.

MSDN defines it as:

> Specifies how an IP address network prefix was located.

I am searching .NET Core repo browser for the implementation of this property, which returns the following enumeration:

```
public enum PrefixOrigin
{
    Other = 0,
    Manual,
    WellKnown,
    Dhcp,
    RouterAdvertisement,
}
```

I could not find in .NET Core repo browser a class that implements `UnicastIPAddressInformation`. In .NET Framework repo browser, I understand the struct `IdAdapterUnicastAddress` is assigned a `PrefixOrigin` by marshaling OS data into C# classes/types. Anyway, I do not know at this point how to determine which enumeration value should be applied to a given IP.

Knowing barely nothing about computer networks, I am researching what is an IP prefix and how to figure it out. The practical example I could find was [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/19774). As far as I understand, however, it provides a way to calculate the prefix length. I still need to know how to determine the `PrefixOrigin` enumeration value to a given IP.

Is it something that can be done by simply taking the prefix length into account ? If not, how do I figure out which `PrefixOrigin` value a given IP should be assigned ?

Answer (score 1):

This field's value is telling you how a configured (or automatically-configured) IP address on the system was determined.

**Manual**: Somebody keyed it into the adapter configuration GUI in control panel or set it using e.g. `netsh` or similar.

**Well Known**: *From a well-known source*.  I'm not really sure if Windows uses this value.  It might be used when a `169.254.x.x` address is assigned in the absence of any other configuration and when no DHCP server is present.

**DHCP**: When a DHCP server automatically assigns an IP address, which is the case in almost all home and office networks (but sometimes not on datacenter networks!), this is how you can tell.

**Router Advertisement**: IPv6 has an automatic configuration system which was supposed to replace DHCP.  To keep things simple, think of this as being functionally the same as the field's DHCP value.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the time to leaving more insights and providing additional help but following me up from [Network exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/70199/19774) to SO!

Comment: By the way I am not sure the selected answer to my NE post answers this question, as the answer shows how to calculate the prefix length, but I need not only the length. Jeff, based on your comment above, by knowing the length I can infer the prefix itself, since I should take the N length first bits of the ip as the prefix. But does this go hand in hand with the method for calculating the prefix length in the selected answer to this post ? you take into account the significant bits only to determine the length - but to get the prefix itself, you consider the original ip, right

Comment: Jeff, so ok, I now know what the field indicates - but how should I manually determine how a given IP was configured, assigning it to one of these 4 categories ? Actually, my code deals specifically with DHCP, so suffices to know how to determine if the ip was configured by DHCP or not.

Comment: By reading the value of this field.  Which API call are you invoking to get the IP addresses configured on interfaces?

Comment: I am using .NET Core's `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`, then `GetIpProperties`, then looping over all `UnicastAddresses` and checking whether they were issued by DHCP or not. When you say *by reading the value of this field* - what does it mean ? Trying to read PrefixOrigin from each of the unicast addresses throws an exception because they have not been implemented in linux (that's my problem :-). Utiimately, the only thing the api returns at this point is the ip string.